# Round() function alternative in C that allows specific rounding rule?

Tags: c, rounding-error

I am running a C exercise for my programming class and I discovered that some calculations are causing a rounding error which in turn, affect a logic statement. Please take a look at last 2 lines of the following code:

```
if (bmi_result < 18.5)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you might be underweight.\n\n", bmi_result);
else if (bmi_result >= 18.5 && bmi_result <= 24.9)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you have a normal weight.\n\n", bmi_result);       
else if (bmi_result >= 25.0 && bmi_result <= 29.9)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you might be overweight.\n\n", bmi_result);
else if (bmi_result >= 30.0)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you might be obese.\n\n", bmi_result);
```

The BMI calculation is `double bmi_result = 703 * weight / (height * height);` If I use a height of 65 (in) and weight of 180 (lb), the result of which being 29.9502, this value gets missed by the if/else statement.

Unfortunately, I am required to follow the BMI parameters exactly as written, as this is a requirement for this problem. Using round() would solve part of the problem (for example, in the specific case I've given), but I would lose precision at other values.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to approach this problem, and make sure the program works accurately for any input? Is there another function similar to round() that allows you to specify rounding to a specific value (nearest tenth)?

Comment: The problem is that since floating-point is usually binary, a number like `24.9` perhaps *cannot* be represented exactly.  So what should "round to nearest tenth" return for `24.901` anyway?

Comment: Typically you'd change your comparison values instead.  So if `bmi_result <= 24.95` you output "normal" and if `bmi_result > 24.95` you output `overweight`.

Comment: Calculate `10 * bmi` as an integer, using integer calculations and rounding, then you won't have to worry about floating point quirks.

Comment: The comparisons should be `if(r<18.5){} else if (r<25.0){} else if (r<30.0){} else {}` That way, the lack of precision with floating point numbers doesn't matter.

Comment: @NateEldredge I guess it should return the same float that it uses for 29.0? I'm not too familiar with the implementation of binary arithmetic in computers. But in the spirit of dxiv's comment I did rounded_bmi_result = round(10 * bmi_result)/10 and it seems fine, both logically and in practice. If you don't mind explaining, what is the discrepancy between this solution and what you say.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (bmi_result < 18.5)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you might be underweight.\n\n", bmi_result);
else if (bmi_result >= 18.5 && bmi_result < 25)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you have a normal weight.\n\n", bmi_result);       
else if (bmi_result >= 25.0 && bmi_result < 30)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you might be overweight.\n\n", bmi_result);
else if (bmi_result >= 30.0)
    printf("Your BMI is %.1f and you might be obese.\n\n", bmi_result);
```

Try this way instead, it should be able to catch the 29.9502 value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this is a school assignment and I have to stick to those specific thresholds with gaps.

Comment: so use *10 then

Comment: Using the common sense this is the rigth solution. It is clear to me that in your school assigment they are assuming the BMI is rounded to one decimal digit, so BMI<30 is equivalent to BMI<=29.9. Otherwise you have values (like 29.95) that does not fit in any range, and this has nothing to do with floating point computer representation, it is just simple mathematics.